# long long int Declared Inside main()

Tags: c, variables, int

> Theatre Square in the capital city of Berland has a rectangular shape
>   with the size n × m meters. On the occasion of the city's anniversary,
>   a decision was taken to pave the Square with square granite
>   flagstones. Each flagstone is of the size a × a.
>
> What is the least number of flagstones needed to pave the Square? It's
>   allowed to cover the surface larger than the Theatre Square, but the
>   Square has to be covered. It's not allowed to break the flagstones.
>   The sides of flagstones should be parallel to the sides of the Square.
>
> **Input**
>
> The input contains three positive integer numbers in the first line:
>   `n, m and a (1 ≤  n, m, a ≤ 10^9)`.
>
> input given: `6 6 4`
>
> **Output**
>
> Write the needed number of flagstones.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
    long long m, n, a;
    scanf("%lld %lld %lld", &m, &n, &a);
    long long req = ceil(m / a) * ceil(n / a);
    printf("%lld", req);    
}
```

It should give me `4` in first test case but it is giving me `1`. I saw a solution where people were using `int m, n, a` as globally declared variables that's above `main()` in that case how they store the value if 10^18 in 4 byte globally declared variable (suppose last test case is very large number). Or is there a different rule when we declare a variable globally? Some of them were passing as `main(m, n, a)` without declaring anywhere.

Comment: What are the values in the faulty case?

Comment: Note that `m / a` and `n / a` perform *integer division*.

Comment: input `1000000000 1000000000 1` output `-2147483648`

Comment: in first case that i have mentioned input is `6 6 4`

Comment: This is an online judge challenge question, which you are supposed to solve. Do you have a question about C?

Comment: @newby `ceil(6/4)` is 1 because `6/4` is 1. That's how integer division works, it truncates the result to an integer. And a `long long` is an integer.

Comment: ok i have asked question about syntax@WeatherVane of declaring variable please tell me about that you can read my doubt above

Comment: Oh, `ceil(m / a)` is already a `floor` because of the integer division (assume no negative values). Most of such questions can be solved with the correct integer arithmetic. Perhaps you should compute the area `m * n` first.

Comment: Using `long long` the square in Berland could be nearly 1000 _light years_ across!  Choose your data types sensibly.

Comment: Not sure where you got 10^18 from!?  The question clearly states `a <= 10^9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With "(1 ≤  n, m, a ≤ 10^9)" there is no need for `double` math or functions.

As `m / a` is *integer* division - which truncates away the fractional portion of the quotient, making `ceil(m / a)` irrelevant - simple look for a remainder to see if one should "round up".

```
// long long req = ceil(m / a) * ceil(n / a);
long long m_over_a = m/a + (m%a != 0);
long long n_over_a = n/a + (n%a != 0);
long long req = m_over_a * n_over_a;
```

---

Note about doing `m/a` and `m%a`.  In days of yore, compilers would perform 2 expensive division/remainder calculations.  Today it is reasonable to expect a good compiler to see the adjacent code and perform a single divide_and_remainder calculation together.  So once `m/a` is done, the cost of `m%a` is typically inconsequential.

Answer (score 2):

You need an integer division that rounds up.

```
int DivideRoundingUp(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    return (numerator+denominator-1) / denominator;
}
```

A version of this using `long long` instead of `int` should provide the right results with parameters up to 10^9

Comment: This is a good 1st step, yet `long long req = DivideRoundingUp(m, a) * DivideRoundingUp(n, a);` will fail to provide the desired result when `m,n` is large..

Answer (score 1):

*int/int* gives an integer result. To avoid problems with precision that may happened when casting to double—especially from 64-bit long long—you should check the remainder of division.

```
long long req = (m / a + (m%a>0?1:0)) * (n / a +(n%a>0?1:0));
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `ceil` function. Conditionally adding 1 already computes the ceiling.

Comment: i declared variable globally as int type and my question is still holding the variable of 10^18 order
but when i am declaring inside main as int instead of long long it showing run time error

Comment: The maximum variable you can store inside int is around 2^31=2147483648, long long can handle 2^63, but if you want to be able to solve problem with input:
`1000000000000000000(1E18) 10000000000000000000(1E18) 1`, you have to implement custom arithmetic - answer is 1000000000000000000000000000000000000(1E36) - outside of long long range.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the calculation of `m/a` and `n/a`.

Because `m`, `n`, and `a` are all integer types, performing division between them perform *integer division*, meaning that and fractional part is truncated.  In your example, you're calculating `6 / 4` which evaluates to 1 due to this truncation.

You need to cast at least one of these arguments to a floating point type such as `double` in order to perform floating point division:

```
long long req = ceil((double)m / a) * ceil((double)n / a);
```

Comment: ok but if i declare any variable globally as int can i store a large number inside that without using long long

Comment: @newby An `int` (or any type) has a fixed size, regardless of where it is defined.

Comment: That is true but in this type of question the solution can often be found by integer arithmetic used appropriately. `double` may not be exact, and may fail by "Time Limit Error".

Comment: `int n,m,a;main(){
 scanf("%d%d%d",&n,&m,&a);

 printf("%lld",(m+a-1ll)/a*((n+a-1)/a));
}` someone solved like this thats why i was asking

Comment: this answer was accepted but he is using int globally but when i am using locally i am failing last test case which is quite large

Comment: here i have doubt related to only the variable declaration not to logic

Comment: @newby That answer works because of how the math is done, not because of where the variables live.

Comment: @newby That's a whole different question than the one you asked. You should consider asking a new question. Post that code, and your code, and ask why that code works, and yours doesn't.